Set your own QGIS plugin folder
In QGIS 3.32 I would like to deactivate the path to the plugin folder in the user profile. The plugins should be managed centrally (company instruction), without the user being able to add new plugins manually in his profile. Users should continue to use their own profile. Only the plugin folder should be predefined. If I set up my own repository, clever users can still add plugins themselves. Now I have managed to define at least an own path of the profile folder in the batch (qgis.bat) with --profiles-path.
Is it possible that this only works with the plugins folder? How can I address subfolders? How can I possibly also use the variable QGIS_PLUGINPATH? Here is the batch.
@echo off
call "%~dp0\o4w_env.bat"
if not exist "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin\qgisgrass8.dll" goto nograss
set savedpath=%PATH%
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass83\etc\env.bat"
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass83\lib;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass83\bin;%savedpath%
:nograss
@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
rem Set VSI cache to be used as buffer, see #6448
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins

start "QGIS" /B "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qgis-bin.exe" --profiles-path C:\test\QGIS\test


My current solution is to use the QGIS_PLUGINPATH variable. So that no plugins are read from the profile folder, the folder is emptied by the batch file. The next step is to consider assigning read-only rights to the plugin folder. But I am still open to other ideas.
